# Is there a name for combining two rings into one in a way we combine reals into complexes?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, we made $\mathbb C$ by defining a multiplication (as $(r,s) \cdot (p,q) = (rp-sq, rq+sp)$) and an component-wise addition (thanks to the comments) over a product of two $\mathbb R$, and prove it to be another ring. I've seen the construction and I think it does not rely on the actual structure of $\mathbb R$ -- it only uses $\mathbb R$ as a ring (I think my statement will also work if we replace all 'ring' with 'field', but I'm not sure, and I want to simplify the details unrelated to my question). So, given any ring $R$, we could apply the same process to get a new ring by defining a multiplication over a product of two $R$. I wonder what is this new ring called and if there's some study on it.

Disclaimer: I'm not talking about the algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$, though it might be equivalent to the algebraic closure. I'd also like to learn about if they're equivalent or not.

Comment: We can extend rings in many ways; I don't know what construction you are specifically referring to, maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: You want to look at the notion of "quotient ring" (by an ideal). The hidden construction from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is that you can see $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: The question can be interpreted in many ways. For example, the construction also gives an algebraic closure of the field $\Bbb R$. So if you "wonder what this new ring is called", also "algebraic closure" is an answer.

Comment: I don't think this question is ambiguous. I think they're asking about, for a given (unital, commutative) ring $R$, the "complex ring", which is $R \times R$ with componentwise addition, and multiplication given by $(r,s) \cdot (p,q) = (rp-sq, rq+sp)$.

Comment: Yes, @preferred_anon 's interpretation is what I was thinking about.

Comment: If you apply that to a ring, you will get another ring. If you apply that to a field $F$, you are only guaranteed to get a ring. If the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible on $F$, the result will be a field, but will not necessarily be algebraicly closed ($\Bbb Q(i)$ is not). But If $x^2+1$ is reducible on $F$, then the result will not be a field. In fact, the ring will have zero-divisors. However, if you make certain adjustments to the procedure and apply it to $\Bbb C$, you can get the quaternions.